# javascript add(push) array with multi data inside auto with loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want add an Array (Data3) with multi data with 2 array before:

```
var Data1 = {2,1,5};
var Data2 = {"a","b","c"};
```

The problem is how to make Data3 auto with loop that like this:

```
var Data3 = [
   {
      label: Data1[0],
      value: Data2[0]
   },
   {
      label: Data1[1],
      value: Data2[1]
   },
   {
      label: Data1[2],
      value: Data2[2]
   }
];
```

If data1 and data2 are dynamic array, can help me to solve that problem for fill Data3 automatically with for/while?

Btw, sorry for my english >.<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm assuming your data is an ARRAY, and the result is also an array:

```js
//this is my proposed solution
function joindata(data1,data2){
    if(data1.length == data2.length){
        var data3 = []
        for(var i=0; i<data1.length ; i++){
            data3.push({label: data1[i], 
                        value: data2[i]});
        }
        return data3;
    }
}


//this is an example of how it should be used
var Data1 = [2,1,5];
var Data2 = ["a","b","c"];
var Data3 = joindata(Data1,Data2);

console.log(Data1);
console.log(Data2);
console.log(Data3);
```

```html
<p> this is here only to print the result </p>
<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using **[`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)**

```js
var Data1 = [2, 1, 5],
  Data2 = ["a", "b", "c"],
  Data3 = [];

Data1.forEach(function(v, i) {
  Data3.push({
    label: v,
    value: Data2[i]
  });
});

document.write(JSON.stringify(Data3));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
var Data3 = Data1.map(function(currentValue, index) {
  return {label: currentValue, value: Data2[index]};
});
console.log(Data3);
```